# Will a Mac mini run two QHD monitors?

Tags: hardware, screen, hdmi, displayport

I have a Mac mini which has hdmi and display port outputs. The spec says it can drive one monitor at QHD and the other at 1900x1200. I have a nice dell u2715h QHD monitor and would quite like my 2nd monitor to be identical... When I upgrade I'll be able to run both at full resolution.

But I can't ascertain if I can run such a monitor at 1900x1200 well in the meantime?

Comment: The specs page for that monitor on support.dell.com should tell you supported resolutions on the monitor. If that exact mode is listed then you are good to go.

Comment: ok so it's just the question of running a expensive monitor at lower resolution, to 'future proof' my desire for two identical monitors for my next PC upgrade :)